# How do I pass arguments from one script to other script ,when variables created or dynamical

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, environment-variables

Scenario Trying to get:-
1)I have a Jenkins job which calls a script followed by some variables 

`ex:- bash ./Firstscript.sh var par car`

- var value could be 123" "456" "789 `Total 3 values in **var** separated by a space`
- par value could be 234" "567    `there are total 2 values in **par** separated by a space`
- car value could be 345" "678  `there are total 2 values in **car** separated by a space`

The jenkins calls `./Firstscript.sh` file and passes the values individually, since the shell treats any space as an another variable.so the values passed to `./Firstscript.sh` are now

---

i)`v1={1} , v2={2},v3={3} ,w1={4} ,w2={5} ,x1={6} ,x2={7}` these are how the values are passing from the first job to the `./Firstscript.sh`

---

ii)Now the`./Firstscript.sh` which has these 7 values will call another script using 
`./Secondscript.sh v1 v2 v3 w1 w2 x1 x2`

My question is that what if the variables **var** has only 2 values ,  **car** has 3 values and variable  **par** has 5 values. how to pass those values to `./Secondscript.sh` dynamically like using `**for** loop , **if** , **while** or any other way of achieving it` .

The `./Secondscript.sh` contains 2 **if** conditions`the first **if** condition will get all the **var** values`, the other `**if** condition gets all the **par** values` and then it does the deployment based on the values.

I have been trying to get this using **$@** but I am not sure how to pass the values to the `./Secondscript.sh` differentiating `which value is **var's** and which value is **par's**` due to lack of complete knowledge in linux/shell I am unable to get to the consensus.  I can explain any doubts regarding this scenario, any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You are trying to pass all the values as received to the second script? Have you tried `$@` ?

Comment: Hi Xiota, I have tried using this at the end of the first script such that all the variable would get passed to the second script , but I am trying to differentiate the variable values, since this script deploys the code based on the values. I have updated my question, since I forgot to add the details "$@".Thank you

Comment: Using spaces as a field separator is an unfortunate choice. You'll have to be very careful how you use quoting for your variables.

Comment: Is the first script able to differentiate which values came from which variable? If not, would seem that's where to start.

Comment: @xiota I am passing var par car variables to the first script which has the values in it. since I do not know how many value can each variable be, I used the values as a string with a space using a for loop `for i in ${A[@]};<br>
do <br>
export PI$k="$i";<br>
k=$(($k+1));<br>
done
export var=$PI1" "$PI2" "$PI3" "$PI4`

Comment: I don't really understand the assertion that *"the shell treats any space as an another variable"* - AFAIK, the shell will treat the whole of `123" "456" "789` as a single argument

Comment: @steeldriver I meant those ar IP address coming from a txt file, so I am using a for loop and get the value to a variable with a spaces as mentioned. but then when I need to pass it to another script the shell is not treating it as a single variable , instead it is taking it as a 3 different variables.